# Entity Framework - Reference itself

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a User table that contains a field that is called CreatedById that is not nullable. When the end user has created a new database I need to create a User account for that user, but then I want to set the createdById field, and the only Id is the Id of the record that I am just saving. So how do I reference the current record that I am saving? Do I need to make CreatedById nullable?

```
            user.CreatedById = ???; // <-- Here is the problem
            user.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
            user.Name = userName;
            database.User.Add(user);
            database.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: If the CreatedbyId is not valid for this user you should be able to set it to either `null` or `0` to show that in your data. I would change your db schema accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to save the user first and then attach the user id to the entity. After the user is saved to the context, using `database.SaveChanges()`, the `user.Id` is filled with the newly created id.

Example:

```
var user = new User();
user.Name = "John Smith";

database.User.Add(user);
database.SaveChanges();

user.CreatedById = user.Id; // user.Id has the created entity id.
database.SaveChanges();
```

One thing I have hard time understanding, why would you want to set the `CreatedById` to the same user id as you are saving?

Comment: Well, since this is the first user in the table, its a new database, how else can I do it? And since CreatedById is not nullable I can't save it without CreatedById first and then change it?

Comment: I would suggest making the user `CreatedById` nullable, since the user does not have a creator. If you know the user is the first user and using `int` as the primary key, you can just set it to `1` or `-1` for an invalid value indicating the system setting it.

Comment: You are probably right about having to make it nullable for the User table, all other tables have CreatedById as not nullable though. I have tried setting it to 1 but when I was debugging this I started to manually truncate the database tables instead of creating a new one. So then Id 1 was already  used, but I guess that can't happen normally. So either one of thoose solutions would work I guess.